# trying to create a userinfo code for discord bot, everything runs fine, but when it loads, the field Joined Server is set as undefined any tips?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm using node and visual studio code.
The script runs fine and the text gets embedded right below the title of the field. But instead of showing the joined server date, it shows 'undefined'.

```
switch(args[0]){
case 'userinfo':         
     let usera = message.mentions.users.first()
     if(!usera) return message.channel.send("Must specify user")
     const joinDiscord = moment(user.createdAt).format('llll')

          let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor(usera.tag, usera.avatarURL)
          .addField("ID", usera.id, true)
          .addField("Username", usera.username, true)
          .addField("Status", usera.presence.status, true)
          .addField("Joined Server",usera.joinedAt, true)//its this part
          .addField("Created", usera.createdAt, true)
          .addField("Bot", usera.bot, true)
          .setTimestamp()
          .setColor(0x0f7fa6)
          .setThumbnail(usera.displayAvatarURL())
     message.channel.send({embed});
                        
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`joinedAt` is a varible for the `guildMember` object type, but what you have is a user object. You can get the member object from the user object by doing the following:

```js
switch(args[0]){
case 'userinfo':         
     let usera = message.mentions.users.first()
     if(!usera) return message.channel.send("Must specify user")
     const joinDiscord = moment(user.createdAt).format('llll')

          let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor(usera.tag, usera.avatarURL)
          .addField("ID", usera.id, true)
          .addField("Username", usera.username, true)
          .addField("Status", usera.presence.status, true)
          .addField("Joined Server",message.guild.members.cache.get(usera.id).joinedAt, true)//got the guild member from the users id
          .addField("Created", usera.createdAt, true)
          .addField("Bot", usera.bot, true)
          .setTimestamp()
          .setColor(0x0f7fa6)
          .setThumbnail(usera.displayAvatarURL())
     message.channel.send({embed});
                        
}
});
```

Comment: Tip: You can make your code even shorter and use: `message.guild.members` instead of `message.channel.guild.members`.